Prime Ideals and Integral Domains - Intentionally Constructed or Purely Coincidental?
This question is made purely out of personal curiosity.
The motivation behind asking this question: Normal subgroups were first truly utilized by Évariste Galois with one of the intents being to induce another object with group structure from an already existing group (i.e. $N\triangleleft G\iff\text{Well-}$$\text{Defined Group }$$G/N$). And similarly, ideal subrings would be first utilized with the intent inducing another object with shared ring structure properties. Being that rings have far more variants (e.g. rings, IDs, PIDs, EDs, fields, etc.) compared to groups (which only really have groups and abelian groups), it’d make sense that we’d be interested in constructing a type of subring which upon taking the quotient would produce another object with ring structure reflect via IDs, PIDs, etc. Hence, mathematicians of the past arrive at prime and maximal ideals…however, it is also equally plausible that prime and maximal ideals were just natural variants of an ideal which by pure coincidence would provide us with a means to induce other objects of potentially more enlightening ring structure.
Does anybody know? I’ve tried looking into this online, though I struggle to find any good answers. Maybe somebody on here has a background on this they’d be able to share?
Thank you for your time as always. (I’m sorry to ask so many questions!)

The history of ideal theory is quite complex (beware simplified / romanticized popularizations). For example, perusing Lemmermeyer's paper on Kummer's seminal work on "ideal numbers" should quickly convince you of the complexity. You will be better prepared to comprehend these matters after you have mastered the modern theory. So I highly recommend that you postpone any serious study of history till then.

Analogous remarks apply to nonhistorical aspects of your question, e.g. you will better equipped to understand congruences and quotients of algebraic structures after you study universal algebra and category theory.  This question (and some of your prior questions) seem to indicate that you are attempting to learn to run before you have learned to walk.

Reducing groups to only "groups and abelian groups" shows that you have a lot to learn about them.
